# Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px' - Bootstrap 4 and Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-sass

I just installed a fresh Laravel 5.4, and bootstrap 4 alpha 6. Laravel mix wont compile SASS:
Here is one error:

```
    Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
$input-height:                   (($font-size-base * $input-line-height) + ($input-padding-y * 2)) !default;
                                ^
      Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
      in /Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss (line 444, column 34)
    at runLoaders (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:192:19)
    at /Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.asyncSassJobQueue.push [as callback] (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:57:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2262:31)
    at apply (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:20:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12)
    at Object.callback (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:944:16)
    at options.error (/Volumes/HDD/nicolae/Dev/htdocs/test/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)

 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

Someone passed this? And how?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved

1. remove the bootstrap entry from package.json and replace it with
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6", in resources/assets/sass/app.scss,
2. comment out the import of variables. change the path of bootstrap to
   @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
3. in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js, look for require('bootsrap-sass');
   and change it to require('bootstrap');

[Link!](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/tip-using-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-with-laravel-54)

Comment: Yes, looks like there's a conflict between the Laravel-provided `resources/assets/sass/_variables` and the variables shipped with Bootstrap v4 a6. Commenting out Laravel's variables fixed this.

Answer (score 23):

It happened to me too, it's like you said, the override of some variables is the cause of this error.

To fix this just comment this line in resources/assets/sass/_variables:

$font-size-base: 14px;

In the variables if you need are using other variables that laravel provides.

reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18368

Comment: You could also simply change `14px`  to  `1rem` — that fixed it for me.

Comment: I've downloaded bootstrap 4 today, and am still getting this issue
$input-height-inner:                    ($font-size-base * $input-btn-line-height) + ($input-btn-padding-y * 2) !default;
                                       ^
      Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px*px'.
$font-size-base is 1rem

Comment: I've downloaded bootstrap 4 today, and am still getting this issue :

$input-height-inner: ($font-size-base * $input-btn-line-height) + ($input-btn-padding-y * 2) !default;
                                       ^
Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px*px'.

$font-size-base is 1rem
$input-btn-line-height is 1.5 (which I've tried changing to 1.5rem)
$input-btn-padding-y is 0.375rem

Answer (score 10):

Just change the 
`$font-size-base: 14px;` 
to 
`$font-size-base: 0.875rem;`

and run 
`npm run dev`

Answer (score 8):

I just fixed this on my side, what worked for me was moving the @import "bootstrap.scss.." and other variables to the top of the app.scss file, it seems it was overwritten and that is what caused the issue.