# Migrate from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.0 with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass

I've started a project with Laravel in version 5.5 including Bootstrap v.3.3.7. For now, I want to test if I can switch to the new 4.0 release.

I've already read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) but I'm not sure that all the code written in my project will work with the new version, also I'm using the bootstrap-sass included in Laravel.

Do I simply need to run :

```
npm uninstall bootstrap
npm install bootstrap
```

To get the new version of the sass preprocessor included or will my code be absolutely broken?

I'm open to any advice because I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"` inside of your `package.json` and run `npm update`, all the changes you need to worry about are [`Breaking`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking) changes when upgrading from `v3.6` to `v4`

**NOTE:**
As the PO mentioned in the comments, on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590808/incompatible-units-rem-and-px-bootstrap-4-and-laravel-mix) you can find which files you need to modify in order to properly load `Bootstrap 4` into your `older Laravel versions`, specifically versions below and including `5.5`.

Comment: After tries, I can tell that [this other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590808/incompatible-units-rem-and-px-bootstrap-4-and-laravel-mix) is truly helping is someone migrate too with Laravel because it was also my problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I completely forgot about possible loading issues with `v4` :D