# Incompatible units px and rem (current solutions don't work)

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, sass, bootstrap-4

So basically I'm trying to use custom sass at work for a project but the npm run watch gives me the following error:

```
Incompatible units px and rem.
```

followed by saying the issue resides here (in _variables.scss):

```
$input-height-base:              ($line-height-computed + ($padding-base-vertical * 2) + 2) !default;
```

(It is needed for the template in a vue.js component for our website)

I've tried solutions from [Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px' - Bootstrap 4 and Laravel Mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590808/incompatible-units-rem-and-px-bootstrap-4-and-laravel-mix) 
so changing

```
$font-size-base: 14px !default;
to
$font-size-base: 1rem;
```

doesn't work. I've also tried the other steps suggested in all of the answers. I've come across another suggestion of commenting out the following in app.scss :

```
@import 'variables';
```

but no luck with that either. Also, inside of bootstrap.js require('bootstrap); is set so it isn't that either.

In case you need to see it,
my component:

```
Vue.component('my-component', require('./components/MyComponent.vue').default);
```

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
});
```

usage:

```
export default {
  name: "my-component",
  props: {
    headerColor: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input: null,
      input:
        "Some example text"
    };
  },
};
```

php file:

```
<div id="example">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

I'm hoping that once it works I'll be able to load my component on our website so I can begin development with it. Any help is appreciated! I hope I've provided enough information as I'm about to leave work for the night but I will try my best to provide more before I get back if needed.

Comment: I don't know anything about sass, but are `$line-height-computed` and `$padding-base-vertical` the same unit? Maybe one is `px` and the other is `rem` ? Maybe `2` is considered `px`?

Comment: It could be but I won’t have access to the code til tomorrow morning. I’m not sure I understand why that would cause an issue

Comment: Because `rem` is a relative unit, `px` is absolute. You cannot know the `px` value of a `rem` number unless you know the root `px` value of `font-size`

Comment: Ohh, maybe that’s it then

Comment: So I changed both so that they are px and still no luck (gives the same error at the same spot of

ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
                                 ^
      Incompatible units px and rem.
    ╷
300 │ $input-height-base:              ($line-height-computed + ($padding-base-vertical * 2) + 2) !default;
    │                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `calc()` function when you have calculations that contain variables of different types.

eg

```
$a: 10px;
$b: 25%;

.mydiv {
  width: calc(#{$a} - #{$b});
}
```

And the `#{}` converts them to string so that sass wouldn't make arithmetic using them while compiling